# Angular: I need to refresh after using CRUD

Tags: typescript, observable, angular7

When I add a new post via my add-post component, it emits the post to my dashboard component. This component contains an overview of all the posts, retrieved via a dataService.

However...

Whenever I do a CRUD operation, I need to refresh my page to view the changes. I figured it has something to do with Observables. I think I'm using them correctly, but they don't seem to work.

```js
export class DashboardComponent {
public filterPostTitle: string;
public filterPost$ = new Subject<string>();
private _fetchPosts$: Observable<Post[]> = this._postDataService.posts$;

public loadingError$ = this._postDataService.loadingError$;

  showAddPost = false;
  constructor(private router: Router, private _postDataService: PostDataService) {
    this.filterPost$.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      debounceTime(300),
      map(val => val.toLowerCase())
    ).subscribe(val => (this.filterPostTitle = val));
  }

  toggleAddPost(): void {
    this.showAddPost = !this.showAddPost;
  }

  get posts$(): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this._fetchPosts$;
  }

  applyFilter(filter: string) {
    this.filterPostTitle = filter;
  }
  addNewPost(post) {
    this._postDataService.addNewPost(post).subscribe();

  }
```

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostDataService {
  public loadingError$ = new Subject<string>();
  public $postsChange = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  get posts$(): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/posts/`).pipe(catchError(error => {
      this.loadingError$.next(error.statusText);
      return of(null);
    }),
    map((list: any[]): Post[] => list.map(Post.fromJSON)),
    share()
    );
  }

  addNewPost(post: Post) {
    return  this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/posts/`, post.toJSON());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an actionsForSucess function and pass to your subscribe something like this to redirect to your new creation.

```
addNewPost(post) {
  this._postDataService.addNewPost(post).subscribe(
    post => actionsForSuccess(post)
  );
}

private actionsForSuccess(post: Post) {

this.router.navigateByUrl('posts', { skipLocationChange: true })
  .then(
    () => this.router.navigate(['posts', 'edit', post.id])
  );
}
```

Comment: In your case you will need add router on constructor. "private router: Router".

Answer (score 1):

Setting `posts$` as getter won't work at all. It's not emiting any values by itself. You will need additional method to fetch posts.

To ensure you will always emit posts after `addNewPost()` method, you can map response after posting and emit fetched posts on your Subject. However, you can also call this method in your DashboardComponent after receiving response from `addNewPost` method (without need to subscribe to `fetchPosts` in your `PostDataService`).

Here's an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kx4cco